# Firefox doesn't interpret XSLT-1.0 anymore

Tags: firefox, xslt

I have a lot of data saved in XML files with XSLT to show the content properly in Firefox. But from today, Firefox doesn't interpret anymore the XSLT and shows a white page or the data in a block.

My current Firefox version is 68.0 (64-bit). Is there a bug with XSLT in the new version or is XSLT only disabled per default in Firefox 68.0?

Comment: Are you opening the XML files locally, or from a web server? In the former case, it might have been affected by this fix: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730

Comment: I open the files locally (file:///home/...)

Comment: It seems the relevant bugzilla bug is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565261 which suggests it is indeed caused by the attempt to fix the security problem Tim C has linked to and that setting `privacy.file_unique_origin` in `about:config` to `false` is a "workaround".

Comment: @MartinHonnen: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim C has pointed out in a comment, due to side effects of a security fix the use of `<?xml-stylesheet href="foo.xsl" ..?>` in XML documents loaded from the local file system is no longer working in Mozilla. The problem is reported as bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565261 but it seems there is no intention to fix it as Chrome and other Chromium based browsers have stopped supporting XSLT referenced in XML documents loaded from the local file system long ago.

The discussions in the bug report, however, suggest that the setting `privacy.file_unique_origin` in `about:config` to `false` is a "workaround".

Keep in mind that it exposes you to the security problem whose fix disabled the use of XSLT referenced by `xml-stylesheet` processing instructions loaded from the local file system.