# Why is my XSL file no longer being applied to my XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I create xml files in a ..\reports directory They reference a stylesheet e.g.: '.\SurveyRespondentList.xsl'

The most recent Firefox Quantum 68.0 (64-bit) does not accept this.
Previous versions have worked over the years
My reports also work on Internet Explorer 11
My applications are open to all and I have been using this approach to create and display database query reports for years.

ALL of the report files are file:// URLs created for the user on their local PC by the programs I created for their use on their local PC. The intent is they can view their reports in most any web browser.
This approach has worked very well for years (~decade).

I asked Mozilla/Firefox:

1. Is the simple functionality I have used for years gone forever? Or will some eventual future patch restore it?

> "The developers are aware that this patch created problems with HTML-based help documentation, but they weren't able to come up with a way to distinguish legitimate local links from potential attack links. In the future, they might come up with something to allow help documentation to work again and hopefully you would be able to benefit from that, but it's not likely to happen soon."

What are the trends in web browsers?
Does anyone know of another approach?
e.g.: Is there a reasonable way to embed the xslt/css within the .xml data file?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='.\MealTimeFoodListReportLIKE.xsl'?>
<dataroot generated='2019-06-14T12:10:19'>
    <ReportTitle>MealTime Food List Report LIKE</ReportTitle>
    <ReportDate>2019-06-14  12:10:19</ReportDate>

    <reportdatetime>14 Jun 2019 12:10:19</reportdatetime>

    <qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>
        <MealTime>3/28/2018 2:06:52 PM</MealTime>
        <Food>ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse - </Food>
    </qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>

    <qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>
        <MealTime>5/18/2018 11:45:53 AM</MealTime>
        <Food>ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse - </Food>
    </qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>
</dataroot>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:fx="#fx-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl fx">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
    <xsl:template match="//dataroot" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <html>
            <head>
                <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
                <title>MealTimeFoodListReportLIKE</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                body
                {
                    background-color:white;
                    color:black;
                    font-family:arial;
                    font-selection-strategy:auto;
                    font-size:9pt;
                    font-stretch:normal;
                    font-size-adjust:none;
                    font-style:normal;
                    font-variant:normal;
                    font-weight:normal;
                }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080">
                <table BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" width="100%">
                <tr><th colspan=" 2" > <big><big><xsl:value-of select="ReportTitle"/> </big></big> &#160; &#160; <small> <xsl:value-of select="ReportDate"/></small></th> </tr>
                            <tr>
     <th>MealTime</th>
     <th>Food</th>
                            </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE">
                            <tr>
   <td align="center">  <xsl:value-of select="MealTime"/>  </td>
   <td align="center">  <xsl:value-of select="Food"/>  </td>
                            </tr>
                        <!-- Prepare for any expressions in the group footer -->
                    </xsl:for-each><!-- Prepare for any expressions in the group footer -->
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

boxed table:

```
MealTime Food List Report LIKE     2019-06-14 12:10:19
MealTime                 Food

3/28/2018 2:06:52 PM    ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse -  
5/18/2018 11:45:53 AM    ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse -
```

Comment: These questions are not about programming.

Comment: One "other approach" is to run a lightweight HTTP server on the local machine, and switch to using HTTP URIs.

Comment: "Is there a reasonable way to embed the xslt/css within the .xml data file?": I think for Mozilla browsers there was one or perhaps still is one, but would that help you if IE does not support it? Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010656/firefox-doesnt-interpret-xslt-1-0-anymore#comment100584931_57010656 has  setting/"workaround", similar like Chrome has one, to bypass the security restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example with the XSLT code embedded in the XML document and referenced by the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE dataroot [
  <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet
    id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='#my-sheet'?>
<dataroot generated='2019-06-14T12:10:19'>
    <ReportTitle>MealTime Food List Report LIKE</ReportTitle>
    <ReportDate>2019-06-14  12:10:19</ReportDate>

    <reportdatetime>14 Jun 2019 12:10:19</reportdatetime>

    <qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>
        <MealTime>3/28/2018 2:06:52 PM</MealTime>
        <Food>ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse - </Food>
    </qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>

    <qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>
        <MealTime>5/18/2018 11:45:53 AM</MealTime>
        <Food>ChocolateMousse - Chocolate Mousse - </Food>
    </qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE>

    <xsl:stylesheet id="my-sheet" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:fx="#fx-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl fx">
        <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="dataroot">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>MealTimeFoodListReportLIKE</title>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        body
                        {
                        background-color:white;
                        color:black;
                        font-family:arial;
                        font-selection-strategy:auto;
                        font-size:9pt;
                        font-stretch:normal;
                        font-size-adjust:none;
                        font-style:normal;
                        font-variant:normal;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body link="#0000ff" vlink="#800080">
                    <table BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" width="100%">
                        <tr><th colspan=" 2" > <big><big><xsl:value-of select="ReportTitle"/> </big></big> &#160; &#160; <small> <xsl:value-of select="ReportDate"/></small></th> </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>MealTime</th>
                            <th>Food</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="qrMealTimeFoodListReportLIKE">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">  <xsl:value-of select="MealTime"/>  </td>
                                <td align="center">  <xsl:value-of select="Food"/>  </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Prepare for any expressions in the group footer -->
                        </xsl:for-each><!-- Prepare for any expressions in the group footer -->
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</dataroot>
```

Works with Firefox 68 and with Chrome 75 too I think.

Comment: If you have the ability to produce this, why wouldn't you use it produce the resulting HTML page instead?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I tried in no way to promote that example as a well structured way to use XML and XSLT but simply tried to show that embedding XSLT in XML is possible and supported by some of the browsers, including Mozilla browsers. Whether it is possible was one of the points raised in the question and I couldn't stuff that example into a comment.

Comment: Thank you,  Ed Bangga for making my sample code presentable.

michael.hor257k, years ago, I wrote the code to take the results of SQL queries and generate .xml and .xsl files for the user to view in most any web browser.

Michael Kay, thank you, but I cannot understand how I could make this help individual users of my programs on their local PCs.

Comment: Martin Honnen, I suggested something like a setting/'workaround' to Mozilla: > 2) Can this patch rollback be handled by some type of script?

"It's not very convenient to try to script changes to Firefox settings files because they are stored in profile folders with a randomized name. Also, I wouldn't recommend rolling back security patches applied to your customers' systems without their knowledge and consent. That might make you liable for a potential data breach."

Comment: Martin Honnen, I was able to follow your example to modify an .xml file with the XSLT code embedded.
In my testing this file worked with Firefox 68 and Firefox 64, but not in IE 11.
The original .xml with .xsl files work in Firefox 64 and in IE 11, but not in Firefox 68.

Comment: michael.hor257k, years ago, I ~ learned how to write the code to create the .xml and .xsl files. For better or worse, that has served well for quite a few years.

Comment: Martin Honnen, do you know if Firefox's changes are part of a broad trend in browsers? If so, is some form of embedding XSLT in XML a good approach? If that is true, can you recommend some references fro me to learn a well structured way to use XML and XSLT?
I wonder if I could create some code to identify the user's default browser and then generate embedded .xml files or generate a .xml , .xsl file pair.

Thank you all for your guidance.

Comment: @anderci, there doesn't seem to be any interest to improve or maintain the XSLT  support in browsers, indeed in the Chromium/Chrome development there have been various initiatives to pull it completely if one looks at archives of there development mailing list/google groups, mainly claimed to reduce memory footprint or security problems or sometimes lack of usage. On the other hand, so far they all failed.

Comment: @anderci, a certain tendency is obviously to not regard IE or Edge as relevant as "other browsers", as you can see in the comments in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1566172 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565261 it is just claimed that Firefox/Mozilla has been adapted to match other browsers.

Comment: I could add a (switch) in my programs to generate the reports in the .xml - .xsl file pair mode or generate the reports in .xml with embedded xslt style information. Can anyone please direct me to a resource on how to do the embedded approach appropriately?

Comment: Thank you. I could understand some of the information from the bugzilla links.

Comment: I am trying to improve the structure of my .xml with embedded xslt I have a small? example file but it is too big to paste in here?  I try to select it and enter [ctrl]k to mark it as code.

Comment: @anderci, consider to ask a followup question as a separate question where can and should show any code you have and the result you want versus the one you get in the question in a well-formatted way, I don't think it makes sense to try to exchange code here in the comments.

Comment: Continued in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172459/trying-to-improve-structure-of-xml-with-embedded-xslt