# Create XSL stylesheet to view XML as HTML offline

Tags: xslt

I've been going through https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp and want to use the same process on my own data but I keep getting errors. What am I missing?

The error in Firefox is
[image]

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
  <identifier>Z:/My Drive/Mangoesmapping/Spatial Projects/2019/DSC/132_Ongoing_Asset_Updates/Working/Sewerage_Updates/Sewerage_Manholes_InspectionShafts.TAB</identifier>
  <parentidentifier>Sewerage Manhole Infrastructure</parentidentifier>
    <keywords vocabulary="gmd:topicCategory">
    <keyword>Infrastructure</keyword>
    <keyword>Sewerage</keyword>
  </keywords>
  <keywords vocabulary="undefined 2">
    <keyword>Sewerage</keyword>
  </keywords>
  <keywords vocabulary="undefined 3">
    <keyword>Manholes</keyword>
  </keywords>
    <extent>
    <spatial minx="322783.17999999999301508" minz="0" crs="EPSG:28355" maxx="337384.35999999998603016" miny="8170597.66000000014901161" maxz="0" dimensions="2" maxy="8181833.33999999985098839"/>
  </extent>
```

The XSL is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="identifier"/></h2>
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="parentidentifier"/></h2>
  <h1>Keywords: </h1>
        <xsl:for-each select="//keywords">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="keyword">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="//spatial/@maxx"/> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed as it does not contain a root.

Answer (score 1):

I added root on your xml

```
<root>
    <identifier>Z:/My Drive/Mangoesmapping/Spatial Projects/2019/DSC/132_Ongoing_Asset_Updates/Working/Sewerage_Updates/Sewerage_Manholes_InspectionShafts.TAB</identifier>
    <parentidentifier>Sewerage Manhole Infrastructure</parentidentifier>
    <keywords vocabulary="gmd:topicCategory">
        <keyword>Infrastructure</keyword>
        <keyword>Sewerage</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <keywords vocabulary="undefined 2">
        <keyword>Sewerage</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <keywords vocabulary="undefined 3">
        <keyword>Manholes</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <extent>
        <spatial minx="322783.17999999999301508" minz="0" crs="EPSG:28355" maxx="337384.35999999998603016" miny="8170597.66000000014901161" maxz="0" dimensions="2" maxy="8181833.33999999985098839"/>
    </extent>
</root>
```

And I tried to modify your xsl like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="identifier"/>
                </h2>
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="parentidentifier"/>
                </h2>
                <h1>Keywords: </h1>
                <xsl:for-each select="//keywords">
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="keyword">
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="//spatial/@maxx"/> 
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And everything is working fine.

Comment: Works well in IE -is there anyway to get it to format properly in Firefox as well?

Comment: Note that a recent update to Firefox meant that it prevents access to locally stored XSLT files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064845/why-is-my-xsl-file-no-longer-being-applied-to-my-xml-file